# Como volver a subir una aplicacion mejorada en otra cuenta de google play console?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play

Tengo un problema al subir una aplicación en la play store.

Anteriormente había subido una aplicacion en una cuenta personal con un nombre que no me gusto. Después me pasaron una cuenta de la empresa para volver a subirlo y en mi cuenta personal de play store console anule la aplicación. Ahora, ya no aparece esta app en la play store, y volvi a subirlo en la nueva cuenta que me pasaron pero me aparece un mensaje que dice:

**"Si enviaste una actualización, la versión anterior de la app aún está activa en Google Play"**

La aplicación lo estoy desarrollando en ionic, en el archivo config.xml cambie el id para que no fuera el mismo como el anterior que subi, pero parece que google play me lo esta marcando como que si estuviera subiendo una version actualizada en otra cuenta de la play store console.

Alguien sabe como podria resolver este problema? Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

El problema:

> "Si enviaste una actualización, la versión anterior de la app aún está activa en Google Play".

en inglés:

> "If you submitted an update, the previous version of your app is still
> available on Google Play".

Tu app va a ser rechazada ya que tratas de subir una aplicación que contiene el mismo nombre de paquete (id o package name) de una aplicación que ya tiene registro para otra cuenta de desarrollador, por lo tanto debes cambiarlo dentro del archivo `config.xml`:

```
 <widget id="<package name>" version="1.0.0">
```

Pero hay algo también muy importante, si esta es otra cuenta de desarrollador debes crear su respectiva signing key para firmar este .apk

Comment: Si claro fue lo que hice... cambiar el id por otro para que no fuera igual.  Y tambien genere una nueva firma con otros datos tal cual para que fuera como nueva. Pero aun asi me lo sigue marcando como si estuviera subiendo una aplicacion actualizada en otra cuenta o en la misma, no estoy seguro si hay otro id que deba cambiar ya he revisado todo y no encuentro la solucion.

Comment: Cambiaste el paquete en la estructura de tu proyecto?

Comment: A que re refieres el paquete? Cuando lo abri en android studi tambien verifique que los archivos tuvieran el  id nuevo

Comment: me refiero a la estructura de los directorios.

Comment: Si claro, en ionic tuve que borrar el proyecto para volver a crearlo.tambien le cambie el id en widget por uno nuevo. Luego cuando me genero el proyecto para android vetifique si el id era el nuevo, genere una llave nueva para la aplicacion y lo compile, luego lo subi a la play store console y me sigio mandando la advertencia de que se trataba de una app actualizada